# trying to pass function arguments in this specific javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to understand the format in which I should pass on the arguments to a specific function. I am planning to use [spinner](https://github.com/reaktor/jquery.spinner) library and you can check it's demo [here](https://rawgithub.com/reaktor/jquery.spinner/master/index.html). I need to specify the minimum and the default values to the function `spinner`. The function in default mode is used as:

```
$('.spinnerExample').spinner()
```

However I need to pass on custom values for `default` and `minimum` values. The definition of the function is as follows:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.spinner = function (opts) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var defaults = {value:0, min:0}
      var options = $.extend(defaults, opts)
      var keyCodes = {up:38, down:40}
      var container = $('<div></div>')
      container.addClass('spinner')....
```

The link to the js file is [here](https://github.com/reaktor/jquery.spinner/blob/master/src/jquery.spinner.js).

I tried `$('.spinnerExample').spinner(5,2)` but this does not work. I am sure the solution is simple but I dont know javascript well so I am not able to crack it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use

```
$(".spinnerExample").spinner({value: 5, min: 2});
```

Note that the `$.fn.spinner` function only a single paramater (`opts`). It is pretty conventional for jQuery plugins to use an object that is merged with a set of defaults to configure the behavior of the plugin.

In this case, the defaults are `{value:0, min:0}`. If you want to override one or more of these values, simply pass in an object with matching keys and custom values.

More examples

```
$(".spinnerExample").spinner({value: 5}); // min will default to 0
$(".spinnerExample").spinner({min: 3}); // value will default to 0
```